# ASP.NET MVC How to apply role-based or authentication-based View rendering?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, custom-attributes

i want to show/hide certain parts of a View based on Authentication-status or Roles. For my controller actions I have extended ActionFilterAttribute so I can attribute certain Actions.

```
<RequiresRole(Role:="Admin")> _
Function Action() as ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

Is there a **similar** way (attributing) which I can use in the Views? (so not like this: [[How can I create a view that has different displays according to the role the user is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409213/asp-net-mvc-roles-views)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409213/asp-net-mvc-roles-views))

Comment: Why did you have to create an ActionFilterATtribute for that? The Authorize attribute takes a Roles parameter.

Comment: Oh right :-)
I created my own just to learn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the user's logged-in roles from the view like this:

```
<% if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")) { %>
        <td>
          <%= Html.DeleteButton("delete", model.ID) %>
        </td>
<% } %>
```

and maybe your extension method with something like:

```
public static string DeleteButton(this HtmlHelper html, 
    string linkText, int id)
{
    return html.RouteLink(linkText,
     new { ID = id, action = "Delete" },
     new { onclick = "$.delete(this.href, deleteCompleted()); return false;" });
}
```

Obviously, I'm using JavaScript to perform an HTTP DELETE to my controller action, to prevent page crawlers from accidentally deleting data from getting my pages.  In my case I'm extending JQuery with a delete() method to supplement the HTTP verb.

Comment: Ok, so using attribute-based view rendering is probably not possible. I should go with If statements...

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I new this existed, but took a while to find.  Here's what I am using:

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        You are not logged in yet. Please log in.
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
            <ContentTemplate>
                You are an Admin.
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Customers">
            <ContentTemplate>
                You are a customer.
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Simple Log in check
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

This allows you to show different content to different users based on their login state or credentials.

Comment: This is WebForms. I believe the original post was about MVC.