# asp.net mvc changing one menu based on which controller is selected from another menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, controller

I am envisioning a site layout like this-

top navigation menu linking to maybe 4 or 5 indexes of different controllers.  each of these sections will be working with different model objects.

Left navigation menu is specific to a controller.  so, for each of the top menu buttons (corresponding to different controllers) I would like the left navigation menu to offer options only specific to the currently used controler.

What's the best way to go about setting this up?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have separate master pages for the views for each controller/category is a possibility, where the specific menu is defined it the master page.

Are these menus static?

Comment: nope- both the top and left navigation are driven off of user's roles

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the different controllers is the right way to go for your top menu given that you've stated each controller would be working with different model objects (which I take to mean different logical divisions).  It makes sense to break logical chunks of your database/models into separate controllers.

As far as the left navigation menu, you could simply use different actions on the controller to service that section **where it makes sense**.  Just think of actions as exactly that... actions.

You could think of StackOverflow itself as following a similar pattern, where there are 5 (or so) controllers along the top of the page, and then there are actions on those controllers.  For example the "users" controller has actions for registering a new account, viewing user details, searching for existing users, etc.  This is a common pattern in the ASP.NET MVC sites I've seen, and ASP.NET MVC itself is geared toward this type of a scenario.

I'm not really sure there's much else to say, but if you have more specific questions, feel free to post them.  I think you're on the right track, though.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks-

what I am not clear on, though, is how i would 'create' the left nav based on the controller.  it can't be strongly typed since different users might have access to different 'actions', via roles.

Comment: Why not?  To me you could make partial views for each role under the controller and then render the partial that matches the role.

Comment: Check here if you need an example of what I'm talking about:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409213/how-can-i-create-a-view-that-has-different-displays-according-to-the-role-the-use/409303#409303

Answer (score 0):

I use custom attribute for this:

```
[LeftMenu("MyMenu")]
public class MyController ...
```

In my base controller, OnActionExecuted checks for the attribute, and use reflection to invoke **CustomMenus.Get{menuname}()**. Then it sets ViewData["leftmenu"]. You can avoid custom attribute if you just use controller's name as menu name.

CustomMenus is a class whose methods return IList<IMenuItem> - but that's my own menu system, you may decide to return classes, partial names, whatever suites your menu system.