# Different start layouts for different user types with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have three types of roles for each of the menu links.

When the Billing guy is logging into the site

how can I determine dynamically the partial.html file that is shown in the content area?

I can not hardcode the content to the first actionlink in the menu, that means that always the Administration is loaded initially.

What can I do in such a case?

[image]

Comment: In an MVC controller when you say `return Partial(x, viewModel)` the `x` part is a string, so you could ask for a `userRole` parameter and then with that you could conditionally get the partial name, otherwise you could make an `Area` for each role and then once the user logs in you could redirect it to the proper area

Comment: @Luiso sounds like an "answer" you should add so you can get some upvotes...

Comment: @ganders just posted my answer, thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767021/render-different-views-for-different-roles-just-by-one-action-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These types of decisions are best made in the Controller.

Example:

```
public HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Administration()
    {
        // Determine the user's role. 
        // "GetRole()" does not really exist on the controller - use your own method.
        string role = GetRole();
        if (role == "Billing Guy")
            return View("AdministrationBillingGuy")
        else if (role == "SalesGuy")
            return View("AdministrationSalesGuy")
        else
            return View();
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several ways to do this.

if you need all users to get the same url/action then you could do something like this

```
public ActionResult Custom(RoleEnum userRole)
{
    switch(userRole)
    {
        case RoleEnum.Admin:
        .....
        return Partial("_adminPartial", viewModel);

       // rest of you cases here
    }
}
```

OR:

```
public ActionResult Custom(RoleEnum userRole)
{
    var view = GetViewByRole(userRole);
    // where GetViewByRole takes the enum and 
    // returns a string with the name of the partial

    return Partial(view, viewModel);
}
```

Another way to do this is, and one that I'd recommend is to make an `MVC Area` for each user requiring a different layout and then at login you can redirect them to the proper `Area`, I recommend it because it allows for deeper differentiation between roles in the UI layer.

Another way to achieve the different layouts (am talking about `MVC Layout Pages` similar to `ASP.Net Master pages`) is to pass a `string Layout` to the view, using the `ViewBag` or any other method you like, then in the `Razor` code you could do something like this:

```
 @model MyViewModel
 @{
      Layout = (string)ViewBag.Layout;
 }
```

I leaved this last one for last as it appears a bit *hacky* to me. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't provided enough information give any explicit direction, but generally, you should just alter your login post action to redirect to a different place depending on some identifying factor like a role (following is pseudocode)

```
// do login

if (user is "Billing")
{
    // redirect to billing action
}

// etc.
```

The only reason you should be switching out partials or views is if you're doing a SPA (single page application) and utilizing JavaScript for routing. In that case, you would just need some endpoint you could hit with AJAX to get the user's "role".

However, I don't think that's what you're actually doing. If you're just using MVC directly, then you should be actually changing the URL, not just loading a different Razor view.

Comment: I need to hide the other links depending  on the Users Role.