# Rendering different View According to User Roles ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Here's what I'm struggling with. I setup the roles in Asp.Net MVC 5 project. I have 2 roles : admin and employee. I want them to go to different views when they Login. How can I do that ?

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    //if user is admin, return View1();
                    //if user is employee, return View2(); 

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Just check the user type, and return View("Admin");

Comment: I tried something like User.IsInRole("admin"), but didn't worked. It seems simple workflow but can't find the code and documentations ... >.<

Comment: How did you add the user to the role?  I have a feeling that apsnet.identity uses claims (ClaimsType.Role) instead of the role table?

Comment: refer to this link : 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/#mbrDB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a view that has different displays according to the role the user is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409213/how-can-i-create-a-view-that-has-different-displays-according-to-the-role-the-us)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a user to a Role or multiple roles after the creation like following:

```
result = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
```

You can easy get the role of the user with following line:

```
bool isAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin")
```