# Different views based on user type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. A user model has 4 properties:

1. First name
2. last name
3. Dob
4. Arabic name

And there are 4 members who will login. Depending on the login member I need to design the view with this 4 columns.

For example if member 1, I only want to show first name and last name.

If member 2, I need to show first name, last name and dob.

I achieved it by creating 4 different views and calling the views according to the member login. I don't think its good way of programming.

Can we store the detail in a sql table and call in view according to the member login?

For example a table with member login id and specify which are the column needs to display for him, then in view read this table and display the model values. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess creating an extra field in your sql table of users like `userTypeID` and filtering views according to `typeID` of current user would do this. Apparently, This is a role based job.

Comment: If you are doing a POC then ok (your thoughts are in right direction). But if you are designing a real application you will have to think of a scalable and manageable solution i.e. what if 4 more diff type of users needs to be added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a view that has different displays according to the role the user is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409213/how-can-i-create-a-view-that-has-different-displays-according-to-the-role-the-us)

Answer (score 0):

This is a role based job, so once you have created your roles for your different members you can simply add

```
[ReadOnlyAuthorize("A specific role")]
```

attribute above your field declaration